how to sign a PSBT (Partially Signed Bitcoin Transaction) in Dogecoin Core?
I have a base64 PSBT contract that I need to sing. and I can not find any method in dogecoin-cli that allows me to do so ( only signrawtransaction).
I know it's possible because I saw extensions Wallet do that.
please any insights.
example of the PSBT:

